# c program about hollow number pattern

Tags: c

Write a C program to print hollow number pattern series using for loop

Input:

```
5
```

OUTPUT:

```
123456
2    5
3    4
4    3
5    2
654321
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  int i, j, m, n, a;
  scanf("%d", &a);
  for (i = 1; i <= a + 1; a++) {
    for (j = 1; j <= a + 1; j++) {
      for (m = 1; m <= a + 1; m++) {
        for (n = 1; n <= a + 1; n++) {
          printf("%d", n);
        }
        printf(" ");
      }
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: What’s the issue here? Did you forget to ask the question?

Comment: Why the nested loop?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

When trying out your code, the program kept going indefinitely due to the makeup of this statement.

```
 for (i = 1; i <= a + 1; a++) {
```

That statement is incrementing the entered value and thus the comparison of "i" to "a" will never be false.

Viewing what you are after for a result, basically there are three modes of printing occurring:

- The initial line printing all of the integer values.
- The intermediate lines printing an incrementing value on the left and decrementing value on the right with spaces in between.
- A final line with all of the integer values printed in decreasing value.

With that I offer up the following refactored code snippet.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define GAP 2

int main()
{
    int a = 0, b = 0;

    printf("Enter size: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    b = a - GAP;

    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)                     /* Print all values on the first line */
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= a; j++)
            {
                printf("%d", j);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        else if (i == a - 1)            /* Print all values in descending sequence on the last line */
        {
            for (int j = a; j > 0; j--) /* Note the decrementing of the counter value */
            {
                printf("%d", j);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        else                            /* Otherwise, print descending numbers with a gap */
        {
            printf("%d", i + 1);
            for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
            {
                printf(" ");
            }
            printf("%d\n", a - i);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Testing this out resulted in the following test output at the terminal.

```
@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/HollowNumber/bin/Release$ ./HollowNumber 
Enter size: 6
123456
2    5
3    4
4    3
5    2
654321
@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/HollowNumber/bin/Release$ ./HollowNumber 
Enter size: 8
12345678
2      7
3      6
4      5
5      4
6      3
7      2
87654321
```

Note the comments about incrementing, decrementing, and testing in the code snippet to explain what is going on.

Give that a try and see if it meets the spirit of your project.